# XML-RPC Interface Feature is not available in Bugzilla

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I am new to Testopia and I want to integrate Testopia with Jenkins for which I am using Testopia Plugin(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Testopia+Plugin).But I am not able to access the  XML-RPC of bugzilla through Jenkins.
I have tried hitting http://bugzillaserver.com/xmlrpc.cgi and I am getting the following error I got an
error `The XML-RPC Interface feature is not available in this Bugzilla`.Please help by providing the steps on how to access the xmlrpc.cgi in bugzilla.( I have installed bugzilla in a windows system )

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an optional Perl module. Likely you need to install Test-Taint. Run checksetup.pl in your Bugzilla directory and it will tell you the command for installing in your environment.